# Дизайн сайта

Tags: дизайн

С чего начать создание дизайна сайта, если я дизайнер, а не програмист?

Comment: Как и в любом творчестве - с копирования чужого.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы дизайнер, то должны знать с чего начинается дизайн :)

Я не дизайнер, но могу предположить, что дизайн начинается с макета, потом цветовая схема и графические элементы.

Answer (score 1):

Нарисуйте свой сайт в фотошопе. Таким, каким вы хотите, чтобы он был. Дальше будет проблема верстальщика. ))

Answer (score 1):

Создание дизайна сайта начинается от поставленной задачи(ТЗ)!

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, удобно работать по некому плану:

1. Дизайн — нарисовать весь макет в фотошопе.
2. Верстка — наверстать сайт, сделать его таким, каким он должен выглядеть; поработать с кроссбраузерностью.
3. Адаптация под движок — адаптировать сайт под php-движок/ucoz и т.п.

Если раньше не было опыта дизайна сайтов - нужно посмотреть готовые макеты, попробовать рисовать что-то похожее, кидать на какие-либо дизайнерские форумы, чо-бы получать критику.

Answer (score -1):

Я считаю, что для начала можно попробовать сделать пробный сайт.
К примеру на юкозе.
Ну, а так выше всё правильно говорят.
Только вариант с фотошопом немного нудным будет.

Comment: А с uzoz'ом жизнь наладится? :D

Comment: Вполне! Там есть визуальный редактор, и много чего можно оттуда взять делая сайт на другом хостинге.;)

Comment: ооо и тут?? не надо советовать не в тему, или ты юкоз рекламишь????
по делу, начинать надо с ТЗ потом макет, потом если есть желание учим html+css... верстаем... ну как то так...